# Batch Dice Game

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am developing a dice game in Batch. The only piece missing is the most important part! I can't figure out how to make a random number generator which generates a number between 1-6! Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code will set `%roll%` to a random number from 1 to 6, inclusive.

```
set /a roll=(%random% %% 6) + 1
```

It uses [`%random%`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490954.aspx), which gives a random number from 0 to 32767, and then uses the [modulus operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) to make it range from 0 to 5.  1 is then added to make this 1 through 6.

Note that this won't be perfectly random, but it should be good enough for your needs.  Since 32767 is not perfectly divisible by 6, there will be a minute bias to rolling 1 and 2 (but this will be small enough that it is not noticeable).

Comment: Also dices are not perfectly random. So the emulation is quite realistic ^^

Answer (score 0):

try out this one, you could improve by adding better animation or more dice.

```
@echo off&&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
title Dice or Die
::by BR4Z1L14N N00B
color 0f

:INICIO
::throwing the die
set/a dd=%random% %%6 +1
::------------------------------------------------
::die rolling time |range: 13~26| change down here for longer or shorter roll
set/a mov=%random% %%13 +13
::------------------------------------------------
set movlim=0
set anim=0

::here the die is rolling, then for the up face there's 4 possibillities for the next face
:GIRO
call :loading
set/a movlim=%movlim%+1
    if %movlim% equ %mov% goto FIM
        if %dd% equ 1 set pos0=4&&set pos1=6&&set pos2=2&&set pos3=3&&goto setDD
        if %dd% equ 2 set pos0=1&&set pos1=6&&set pos2=5&&set pos3=3&&goto setDD
        if %dd% equ 3 set pos0=1&&set pos1=2&&set pos2=5&&set pos3=4&&goto setDD
        if %dd% equ 4 set pos0=1&&set pos1=3&&set pos2=5&&set pos3=6&&goto setDD
        if %dd% equ 5 set pos0=4&&set pos1=3&&set pos2=2&&set pos3=6&&goto setDD
        if %dd% equ 6 set pos0=4&&set pos1=5&&set pos2=2&&set pos3=1&&goto setDD

:FIM
cls
echo.
echo/ %dd%
pause>nul
set dd=
set mov=
set xlado=
goto INICIO

:setDD
set/a xlado=%random% %%4
set dd=!pos%xlado%!
goto GIRO

:loading
set load=
set delay=0
set rollx=ó
:loopd
set/a delay=%delay%+1
::------------------------------------------------
::animation speed, |delay 30| change down here to get faster or slower
    if %delay% neq 30 goto loopd
::------------------------------------------------
if %anim% equ 0 set roll=-&&set anim=1&&goto prx
if %anim% equ 1 set roll=\&&set anim=2&&goto prx
if %anim% equ 2 set roll=%rollx:~1,1%&&set anim=3&&goto prx
if %anim% equ 3 set roll=/&&set anim=0&&goto prx
:prx
set load=%load%%roll%
cls
echo.
echo/ %load%
exit/b
```

Answer (score -1):

```
:random_1
Set /a roll=%random%
If %roll%==gtr goto random_1
If %roll%==lss goto random_1
If %roll%==1 goto next_step
```

And so on

Comment: I would be very surprised to see `%random%` return something like `gtr`